# .iterator() Producing Null Pointer Exception Even When Checked For Null

Tags: java, android, arraylist, iterator

I am doing some threading. In the postExecute I need to perform an iterator task. I check if the iterator() is null, but it's still producing this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
        at co.appname.app.Fragments.F_EditPhoto$FiltersAsyncTask.onPostExecute(F_EditPhoto.java:772)
```

Here is my code, Im checking for what I think is every possible null scenario. Can you advise what I am doing wrong?

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
        {
            List<K_FilterPreview> filtersCache = _positionToFiltersCacheMap.get(_selectedEditImage.position);
            if (filtersCache == null || filtersCache.iterator() == null)
            {
                System.err.println("Filter cache was null");
            }

            // THIS IS THE LINE THROWING THE ERROR!
            Iterator<K_FilterPreview> i = filtersCache.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext())
            {
                //Do stuff
            }
        }
```

This only occurs if I try to start this event as soon as the current event is done processing. If I wait a few seconds before invoking this it works fine. So there is something going on with the threading but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (filtersCache == null || filtersCache.iterator() == null)
{
     System.err.println("Filter cache was null");
}
```

Well if `filtersCache` is null, you just print an error statement, and then the program *continues* to call `iterator` on the null `filtersCache`. You probably wants to just return from the method in that case. Further, normally when you get an `Iterator` on a list, it doesn't return null so I don't think there is a need for the second part in the condition:

```
if (filtersCache == null)
{
     System.err.println("Filter cache was null");
     return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that `filtersCache` is not `null`, then call `.iterator()`

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
    {
        List<K_FilterPreview> filtersCache = _positionToFiltersCacheMap.get(_selectedEditImage.position);
        if (filtersCache == null || filtersCache.iterator() == null)
        {
            System.err.println("Filter cache was null");
        }

        // THIS IS THE LINE THROWING THE ERROR!
        if(filtersCache != null && filtersCache.iterator() != null){
            Iterator<K_FilterPreview> i = filtersCache.iterator();

            while (i.hasNext())
            {
                //Do stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A single else solves the problem. No reason to check `!= null`